# detect, if ctrlp is opened/active

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I like the `relativenumber`s, but they turn out to be slow if I move through files with very long lines. So I added

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * if &relativenumber | set norelativenumber | endif
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * set relativenumber
set updatetime=500
```

to my vimrc. It disables relative numbers during cursor movement and enables them afterwards again. However, this also enables them in ctrlp. Especially since ctrlp disables `number`, this causes columns to jump as soon as I cursor. Is there a way to detect, if I'm currently in the curlp file browser?

Answer (score 2):

The CtrlP scratch buffer probably has a distinct name (`if bufname('') =~ 'ctrlp')`) or filetype (`if &filetype ==# 'ctrlp'`) that you can use in a condition on a similar `autocmd BufEnter`.

(Note: I don't use the plugin, so the above names are just for illustration.)